# How do I insert a new timeuuid and retrieve the inserted value?

Tags: cassandra, timeuuid

I'm inserting some data into a Cassandra table(/column family), and I need to generate a unique key. I've decided to use `timeuuid` for this, as it gives me nice sortability as well as uniqueness. I can use the `now()` function to generate the timeuuid, as in this CQL code:

```
insert into uuidtest ( something, else ) values ( now(), 'hola' );
```

The problem with this technique is that I have no idea what value I just inserted. I need to know this, as I'm going to need to use it later.

How can I retrieve this value at the time that I insert it (as I certainly can't guarantee that nobody else will insert one immediately after me)?

Answer (score 1):

What Cassandra client are you planing to use? I don't think its possible to do this using plain cqlsh. But using a client API would allow you to create a timeuuid value separately and provide it as part of your insert statement along with the other values.

Comment: Good answer...I was thinking pretty much the same thing.  Although, if the OP wants to sort by the timeuuid, then using it as a partiton key won't do him a whole lot of good.

Comment: I'm using the Datastax .NET client. The problem with generating them client-side is you have no guarantee of uniqueness.